# Different ways of animating between a series of images in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I have a series of image (PNG) files, about 50 of them. If displayed quickly one after another they form a smooth animation.

How can I create this animation in Cocoa, within an NSView? What method would you suggest, and how would you go about doing it?

Most answers here seem to suggest Core Animation, but I need it to be in an NSView which accepts mouse events and drops, so I'm not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Animation is best way to display a smooth animation.

NSViewAnimation also can create a animation, but may not smooth as Core Animation.

NSView also can add Core Animation layer.

[NSView setWantLayer:YES]

In your question, You want accepts mouse events.So, I suggest to Use Core Animation to display animation at NSView,As NSView just accept events,and let layer to animation.

Sorry about my poor English,Hope I expression clearly. :)